# Forcing enumerated list to put words underneath the numbers

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, enumitem

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it.

I want to create lists in using `\enumerate` where, if a passage of text for a particular item is long enough, then the text runs under the number for that item.

A mws:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text before list.
\begin{enumerate}[{\normalfont (1)},leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt]
\item A sentence which is just long enough to ensure that I need to go onto the next line.
\item Some more text.
\end{enumerate}
Text after list.

\end{document}
```

In the above, I would want the word ''line'', which appears at the start of a new line when I compile this, to be below the (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `wide` option. Might also be an idea to play with the `itemindent`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),wide,itemindent=\labelsep]
\item \kant[1]
\item \kant[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]